# Print rpath of an executable on macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, dynamic-linking, darwin

I want to change the *rpath* of an executable using `install_name_tool`, but I can't figure out what the *rpath* is right now. `install_name_tool` requires both the old and the new *rpath*'s to be given on the commandline. What command can I use to print the *rpath* of an executable under macOS?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

First of all, understand that an executable doesn't contain a single `rpath` entry, but an array of one or more entries.

Second, you can use `otool` to list an image's `rpath` entries. Using `otool -l`, you'll get output like the following, at the very end of which are the `rpath` entries:

```
Load command 34
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 88
         name /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 19:00:02 1969
      current version 1038.32.0
compatibility version 45.0.0

Load command 35
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 40
         path @loader_path/../Frameworks (offset 12)
```

Look for the `LC_RPATH` commands and note the path under the `path` entry.

EDIT: regarding what `@loader_path` is: it's a generic and dynamic way to refer to the Mach-O object that wants to do the loading of the framework.

While this is a rather contrived example, I think it should get the point across. Let's say we have an app `MyApp.app` that uses a framework `MyFramework.framework`. We'll also say that to function properly, I require that my app is installed in the /Applications and nowhere else. So the structure of said app and framework would be the following:

`/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` (executable)
`/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework` (Mach-O dylib)

If we were to run `otool -L` (note the capital L) on the executable it would show the following regarding MyFramework:

```
@rpath/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework
/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
....
```

Note that because the MyFramework.framework uses an `@rpath` install name/path, we'll need to have runtime search path entries that will be substituted in place of `@rpath` at runtime. Now, I could have a single rpath entry of:

```
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks
```

That would work, and at runtime the two parts would be put together:

`/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks` + `/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework` ==

```
/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/MyFramework
```

Obviously, hard-coding a path like this is not ideal, as simply moving the app to a different folder or renaming the app itself would cause linking to fail.

`@loader_path` is simply a dynamic way to refer to the app's executable wherever it may exist on the filesystem. In this particular case, at runtime it will be filled in with the path to the running executable: `/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`. Then we can say that to find the MyFramework.framework, you simply go up a directory and over to `Frameworks`.

Comment: What's the `@loader_path`?

Comment: @nn0p I found [this article](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath) helpful in understanding loader_path.

Comment: I couldn't see an LC_RPATH in my otool -l output, but I do see the install name under the name field that follows the LC_ID_DYLIB cmd entry

Comment: Note that CMake decided _forever_ ago at this point (starting with 3.0!) to switch over to using `@rpath` by default, as they [consider it](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MACOSX_RPATH.html#prop_tgt:MACOSX_RPATH) "a more flexible and powerful alternative to `@executable_path` and `@loader_path`". The basic logic is, all libs get linked and identified as `@rpath/libname.dylib` — no concrete paths. With rare exceptions, that's good enough as long as your executable has `LC_RPATH` entries for their installed location(s). You don't have to fiddle with post-install library updates.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `otool -l myexecutable`, but this prints a lot of unnecessary information if you are interested only in the list of *rpath*s.

You can filter the output of `otool -l` to the relevant *rpath* entries by

```
otool -l myexecutable | grep RPATH -A2
```

Answer (score 7):

I found that I can print the install name of a shared library on macOS using

```
otool -D mylib
```

Moreover, I can set the install name directly without reference to the old install name by passing the `-id` flag to `install_name_tool`:

```
install_name_tool -id @rpath/my/path mylib
```

Answer (score 3):

You can display the RPATHs defined in a binary file with `otool -l`, but the output isn't very "human-readable":

```
# otool -l /usr/bin/php
...
Load command 32
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 136
         path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.Internal.sdk/usr/lib (offset 12)
...
```

So, here's a shell function that parses `otool -l` output and prints the RPATHes found, one per line, using `awk`:

```bash
lsrpath() {
    otool -l "$@" |
    awk '
        /^[^ ]/ {f = 0}
        $2 == "LC_RPATH" && $1 == "cmd" {f = 1}
        f && gsub(/^ *path | \(offset [0-9]+\)$/, "") == 2
    '
}
```

<sup>**remark:** given `otool -l` output format, there's no way to prevent a broken multi-line RPATH from fooling the code. I added a little safeguard with the `2 == gsub(...)` which should filter out most of them.</sup>

---

Example:

```bash
lsrpath \
    /System/Library/CoreServices/UAUPlugins/InternationalAccountUpdater.bundle/Contents/MacOS/InternationalAccountUpdater \
    /System/Library/CoreServices/UAUPlugins/DockUpdater.bundle/Contents/MacOS/DockUpdater
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/swift
@executable_path/../Frameworks
@loader_path/../Frameworks
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Swift
/usr/lib/swift
```

Comment: Not a Bash-3 specific trick, but I recommend writing a comment at the top of every script that explains what it does. It's not ideal to have to read the code to figure out why a tool exists.

Answer (score 0):

I just use otool command

```
otool -l <my executable>
```

It prints out the rpath field. No need for any long scripts.

Comment: I also don't like long scripts in SO but when you have to modify programmatically the RPATH of all the binaries in a software package then you'll need to write some.