# qmake - QMAKE_RPATHDIR doesn't work

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmake

I have mac os x. I have application and it needs to use shared library (framework on mac), that is developed as separate project, but concurrently and in Qt 5 too.

**App.pro**

```
.
.
else:mac: LIBS += -F$$OUT_PWD/Frameworks -framework library1
.
.

QMAKE_RPATHDIR += /usr/lib
```

firstly, i am telling to qmake, that library1 will reside in it's bundle in Frameworks directory (this is no problem, linking is done success)

secondly, `QMAKE_RPATHDIR` should tell to gcc compiler, that when app's libraries are located, it should look to those paths in `QMAKE_RPATHDIR` too. I specified `/usr/lib`, just to check if it will work, but:

```
otool -l app
```

doesn't show up any `LC_RPATH` (i am expecting there will be one record for `/usr/lib`) as in here [Print rpath of executable on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521802/print-rpath-of-executable-on-osx)

I really need to setup my development environment (Qt 5, Mac OS X, one base application, one core library (this will act's as SDK for plugins too) and additional plugins (shared libraries too).

**ERROR is still:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: library1.framework/Versions/1/library1
  Referenced from: /Users/Krab/projects/qtProjects/build-rootProject-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_clang_64bit-Release/app/app.app/Contents/MacOS/app
  Reason: image not found
```

this is obvious, because the settings in `.pro` files is just for linking and doesn't resolve the dynamic loading of those libraries (which should be resolved by that `QMAKE_RPATHDIR` directive).

Answer (score 6):

You need to build your framework with the correct install name. For example:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_SONAME = -Wl,-install_name,@rpath/
```

Then in your application,

```
osx:LIBS += -F$$OUT_PWD/Frameworks -framework library1
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += /usr/lib
```

If your resulting "library1" framework is placed in /usr/lib, then your application should load fine. However, in almost all cases you'll want the framework placed inside your application bundle, like so:

```
myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/library1.framework
```

In that case you'd set the rpath in your application a little differently, like so:

```
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += @executable_path/../Frameworks
```

Comment: QMAKE_RPATHDIR did not change anything for me... tried absolute path and executable_path.... it doesn't find the dylib in the framework... Only if I execute post build install_name_tool -add_rpath does it work...

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += install_name_tool -add_rpath <path to look in> $$TARGET
```

to your .pro file - where < path to look in> is the path you framework or dylib resides.

for example, if you place the framework right next to your executable, use

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += install_name_tool -add_rpath @executable_path $$TARGET
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a simple dylib instead of a framework linked to my executable. I had the following already:

```
LIBS += -L/path-to-mylibrary/ -lmylibrary
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += /path-to-mylibrary/
```

`QMAKE_RPATHDIR` was working as my executable listed the `LC_RPATH` command correctly (obtained by `otool -l myexecutable`):

```
Load command 25
          cmd LC_RCPATH
      cmdsize 56
         name /path-to-mylibrary/ (offset 12)
```

However, my resulting executable listed the `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` command for my library as follows:

```
Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name libmylibrary.dylib (offset 24)
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992190/1525238), I updated the `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` command to include the RPATH when looking for the dylib by adding the following to the .pro file of my executable application:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += install_name_tool -change libmylibrary.dylib @rpath/libmylibrary.dylib $$TARGET
```

Afterwards, my executable started listing the `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` command correctly:

```
Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name @rpath/libmylibrary.dylib (offset 24)
```

As a side note, mylibrary is actually a qml plugin deployed into `/qt-install-root/qt-version/platform/qml/Mylibrary/` and is loaded also from the QML engine in other projects.