# macdeployqt and -use-debug-libs

Tags: macos, qt, macdeployqt

I want to build a dmg with a executable with debug symbols so I can take to
another machine and debug it there. If I use macdeployqt with -use-debug-libs
the dmg does seem to have debug symbols and I can use it on the machine it was
built on.

But when I copy the dmg to another mac it fails with:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL
Reason: image not found
```

If I build the dmg without -use-debug-libs and copy the dmg to
another machine it does work. This seems like a bug in macdeployqt.

More info:

They both reference the same lib:

```
@rpath/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 5.5.0, current version 5.5.1)
```

The non-debug Frameworks dir has this:

```
lrwxrwxr-x  1 LarryMartell  staff   25 Mar 15 11:00 QtOpenGL -> Versions/Current/QtOpenGL
lrwxrwxr-x  1 LarryMartell  staff   26 Mar 15 11:00 Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
drwxrwxr-x@ 4 LarryMartell  staff  136 Mar 15 11:00 Versions
```

And the debug one has this:

```
lrwxrwxr-x  1 LarryMartell  staff   31 Mar 15 10:41 QtOpenGL_debug -> Versions/Current/QtOpenGL_debug
lrwxrwxr-x  1 LarryMartell  staff   26 Mar 15 10:41 Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
drwxrwxr-x@ 4 LarryMartell  staff  136 Mar 15 10:41 Versions
```

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem right.  What `QtOpenGL.framework` is the non-debug executable using on this other machine?

Comment: I updated the question with more info.

Comment: So this is a `.app` with the Qt frameworks shipped in the `Frameworks` folder of the app bundle?  Also have you checked the runpath of the executable (I think you use `otool` for that too)?

Comment: Yes, the QT frameworks are in the Frameworks folder of the app bundle. Not sure how to check the runpath. But this may be a known bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48800

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521802/print-rpath-of-executable-on-osx).

Comment: It's the same for both: `@executable_path/../Frameworks (offset 12)`

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? Hitting this with 5.13.1

Comment: same problem with 5.13.2 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80202